# How to backup MySQL database from NSIS

Tags: installation, command-line-arguments, nsis, mysql, database-backups

I need to backup a MySQL database from an NSIS installer. I am missing something trivial in the scripts I tried:

```
nsExec::Exec '"$mySqlDirectory\bin\mysqldump.exe" --user=$username --password=$password --routines $dbName --execute="source D:\$dbName.sql"' $0

nsExec::Exec '"$mySqlDirectory\bin\mysqldump.exe" --user=$username --password=$password --routines $dbName --execute="D:\$dbName.sql"' $0

nsExec::Exec '"$mySqlDirectory\bin\mysqldump.exe" --user=$username --password=$password --execute="--user=$username --password=$password --routines $dbName D:\$dbName.sql"' $0

nsExec::Exec '"$mySqlDirectory\bin\mysqldump.exe" --user=$username --password=$password --routines $dbName "D:\$dbName.sql"' $0

nsExec::Exec '"$mySqlDirectory\bin\mysqldump.exe" --user=$username --password=$password /c echo --routines $dbName > "D:\$dbName.sql"' $0

ExecWait '"$1" /C "$mySqlDirectory\bin\mysqldump.exe" --user=$username --password=$password --routines $dbName > "D:\$dbName.sql"' $0

ExecWait '/C "$mySqlDirectory\bin\mysqldump.exe" --user=$username --password=$password --routines $dbName > "D:\$dbName.sql"' $0

StrCpy $BACKUPFILE "D:\ctvi.sql"
StrCpy $1 $BACKUPFILE
ExpandEnvStrings $2 %COMSPEC%
ExecWait '"$2" /C "$mySqlDirectory\bin\mysqldump.exe" --user=$username --password=$password $dbName > $1' $0

ExecWait '/C "$mySqlDirectory\bin\mysqldump.exe" -u$username --password=$password -R $dbName >"D:\$dbName.sql"' $0
```

None of them worked. Passing argument is not my strongest suit :(

Comment: NSIS syntax looks fine for me. Are there any parameters with spaces? In that case use quotes for them like --user="$username". To debug cmd line parameters use FileWrite (http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.5.8) and write everything to .bat file. Then try to execute .bat file and see the results.

Comment: @Slappy no there are no spaces anywhere. I am not sure which NSIS syntax looks fine for you from the lot I mentioned. Anyway below I got a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
StrCpy $1 "D:\ctvi.sql"
ExpandEnvStrings $2 %COMSPEC%
ExecDos::exec /NOUNLOAD '"$2" /C "$mySqlDirectory\bin\mysqldump.exe" --user=$username --password=$password $dbName > $1' $0
```

Its important not to include the path `"D:\ctvi.sql"` as such in the execute command, also not to quote the path variable. That is why I have used `$1`, that too without quoting.