# Installer installing on two machines

Tags: installation, windows-installer, nsis

I need to create one installer which will install components on two different machines.Windows services and web services on "APP Server" and database part on "DB Server". SQL Server 2005/2008 will be already present on DB SERVER. But it may use different port than default port for sql server.

What things I will require in order to implement this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply a matter of bundling a SQL script with the installer and executing the script by calling sqlcmd with ExecWait.

We can run a script using a trusted connection via:

```
sqlcmd -S _SERVER\_INSTANCE_ -d _DBNAME_ -i _SCRIPT_FILE_
```

Or with a SQL Login:

```
sqlcmd -S _SERVER\_INSTANCE_ -d _DBNAME_ -U _USERNAME_ -P _PASSWORD_ -i _SCRIPT_FILE_
```

For performing actions on remote SQL Server engine native driver is required.In SQL Server 2005 or later the command line client is called sqlcmd.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create 2 radio buttons:

(o) Install  - App Server

( ) Install  - DB Server

User select one item and appropriate components will be installed. (like .dlls, .exes, ... on app server and data files or sql scripts [also scripts can be executed] on db server).
Everything packed into single installer.

Also there should be some custom page(s) (created using nsDialogs) where user can set parameters(port, server name, name of db, path to db, ...)

Comment: Thanks Slappy. But SQL server is installed on other machine and I need to create databases on that machine only.
Can you tell me how installer will run sql scripts on this machine machine?

Comment: Many SQL servers accept parameters so create your sql script and save it as file and launch SQL server with this file as parameter (based on type of SQL server). Check this mySQL example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638294/how-to-backup-mysql-database-from-nsis

Comment: Thanks Slappy for your suggestions. I was able to do it using SQLCMD driver.